# Integrating Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4 with crispy forms

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-crispy-forms, django-bootstrap3

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4 (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).
Using bootstrap3/django1.9/crispy-forms

I found django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker (https://github.com/nkunihiko/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker).

As I've had feedback this doesn't show research, I have read all the documents at the sites above, and I am not sure why the datepicker is not appearing. I am unsure how to debug further than looking at the rendered HTML, the rendered source HTML and the various inspections in Firefox (but I may be doing that wrong I don't know).

I'm just really not sure how to use this in crispy forms - would really appreciate a steer, am fairly new to django but my python is "ok".
I'm unsure if it would be better to:
(1) use the java directly in a crispy template attached through the a Field()
(2) somehow attach the widget from the second link/package in the ModelForm

My Layout is set in a ModelForm.
Form is rendered through a class based view.

I've been attempting option (1)

From the ModelForm

```
AccordionGroup('Other Information','referrer',
                       Field('first_contact_date', template='customers/datepicker_field.html'),
                                  'do_not_contact')
```

Then that template looks like this:

```
{% load crispy_forms_field %}

<div id="div_{{ field.auto_id }}" class="control-group{% if form_show_errors and field.errors %} error{% endif %} {% if field.field.widget.attrs.class %} {{ field.field.widget.attrs.class }}{% endif %}">

    {% if field.label %}
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="control-label {% if field.field.required %}requiredField{% endif %}">
            {{ field.label|safe }}{% if field.field.required %}<span class="asteriskField">*</span>{% endif %}
        </label>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
            {% crispy_field field %}
            <span class="add-on {% if active %}active{% endif %}">{{ crispy_appended_text|safe }}</span>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('{{ field.id_for_label }}').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>

        {% include 'bootstrap/layout/help_text_and_errors.html' %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I have all the various js & css included in the relevant form, and things appear to render OK, e.g.

```
<div id="div_id_first_contact_date" class="control-group "> <label for="id_first_contact_date" class="control-label requiredField">
            First Contact Date<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls"> <div class="input-append"> <input class="dateinput form-control" id="id_first_contact_date" name="first_contact_date" type="text" value="23/02/2016" /> <input id="initial-id_first_contact_date" name="initial-first_contact_date" type="hidden" value="2016-02-23" /> <span class="add-on "></span> </div> <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('id_first_contact_date').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script> </div>
</div>
```

Doesn't work though... although the form field all still works fine... no picker...

All advice (including any readmes I've missed) gratefully accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered my error, if anyone passes by...

$('{{ field.id_for_label }}').datetimepicker();

should have been

$('#{{ field.id_for_label }}').datetimepicker();

Answer (score 0):

You should also import jQuery and Bootstrap JS at the head of the form template (for some reason, the datepicker doesn't appear if they are imported in a template the form inherits from, eg. your base.html).